# VS Code Debugger with Cucumber

Tags: playwright

I've recently installed the Playwright test for VS Code extension in VS Code for Mac, but it doesn't seem to be picking up our playwright tests due (I think) to the fact we have Cucumber layered on top of it. Is there support for Cucumber and, if so, can you point me towards some documentation on how to get it (debugging, tracing, especially) to work?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems you're right and no one has developed an extension that caters to Cucumber tests running on the Playwright framework yet.

Right now I can find:

1. (As you've mentioned) Playwright test for VS Code - Playwright tests only. Does not work when the test is triggered from the Cucumber's feature/scenario structure
2. Cucumber Test Runner - Cucumber tests only. Picks up and runs Cucumber features/scenarios and provides a nice visual indication of the status of each test
3. Cucumber Quick - I believe this can be configured to easily run individual Cucumber tests using the Playwright framework, however it doesn't provide any visual feedback of the test outcome, so the need for that extension can be circumvented with the slightly more clunky method of using tags and profiles

I suspect the reason for this is because Cucumber and Playwright are two separate testing frameworks, each with their own debugging and testing features with overlaps. So integrating the debugging and tracing within a single VS Code extension might be technically complex/not feasible.

Sorry, I know this isn't the most useful of answers, but I thought I'd provide some documentation after looking at a few extensions over the course of a week.

Would love to know if anyone else is working on developing a Cucumber/Playwright Test Runner/Explorer, and will update if things change!